# ESLint shows error on screen import from @testing-library/react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, react-testing-library

When importing the screen function from `@testing-library/react`, ESLint shows the following error:

> ESLint: screen not found in '@testing-library/react'(import/named)

```
// render is imported properly
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
```

The test runs normally and they all pass, but Typescript ESLint still shows the red indicator.

Also tried adding

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...,
    "types": ["@testing-library/react"]
  },
  ...
}
```

but it didn't work.

Update [2022-08-25]:

I'm also using eslint-plugin-testing-library.

```
  extends: [..., 'plugin:testing-library/react'],
  plugins: [..., 'testing-library'],
```

Comment: do you have eslint plugin installed for react-testing library? please check https://kentcdodds.com/blog/common-mistakes-with-react-testing-library#not-using-testing-library-eslint-plugins

Comment: I did, yes! Updating the question with this info!